# Create customers clusters based on sales percentages in SQL

Tags: javascript, sql

I have data set looks like below

[image: Data]

I want to create the last column cluster with below logic. Need to pickup first 3 ID always in cluster. But there is condition, after picking first 3 ID, check for each ID % of individual ID is less than equal to 70 for that group. So for example, for `ID =1`, check % as `1000/(1000+500+400)` similarly for `ID=2`, `500/(1000+500+400)`. This we need to check for individual ID of this group. Here, for all 3 IDs we have % `<=70%` , hence we group them as 1.

Now, take next 3 group of IDs and do the same process as described above. But here catch is if any of the group ID's % `>70` then we need to pick up next ID in grouping and follow the same process until we get the % `<=70`.

For example when we first checked % of `ID=4`, `300/(300+50+70)` which is more than `70%`, due to which we add next ID in grouping and if now we calculate the % for `ID=4`, it becomes `300/(300+50+70+40)` which is less than `70%`. So now we grouped `ID=4`,5,6,7 as cluster 2.

We need to follow this same process and remaining IDs will go to 0 cluster

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Are the `sales` always ordered?

Comment: Do you have -ve values for sales?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Code

```
--create table customers
    --( product varchar (200),
    --ids int,
    --sales numeric(18,4)
    --);


    --INSERT into customers values ('A',1,1000);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',2,500);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',3,400);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',4,300);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',5,70);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',6,50);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',7,40);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',8,30);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',9,30);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',10,30);
    --INSERT into customers values ('A',11,20);

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Id INT=0,
            @cluster INT=1,
            @max_irow INT ,
            @max_cust_id INT 
        
    
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Customers') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Customers

    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ids) AS irow,
        Product,
        Ids,
        ISNULL(Sales,0.00) AS Sales,
        0 AS Cluster 
    INTO #Customers
    FROM customers WITH(NOLOCK)

    SELECT @max_cust_id=@@ROWCOUNT

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_Cluster') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp_Cluster

    SELECT *,CAST(0.0000 AS NUMERIC) AS Percntg 
    INTO #tmp_Cluster 
    FROM #Customers WHERE 1=2

    WHILE(1=1)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #tmp_Cluster(irow,Product,Ids,Sales,Cluster,Percntg )
        SELECT  irow,product,ids,sales,@cluster,sales/SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY ISNULL(Cluster,1))*100
        FROM #Customers
        WHERE Cluster=0 AND irow<=@Id+3

        IF @@ROWCOUNT<3
        BREAK;
     
    
        WHILE(1=1)
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #tmp_Cluster WHERE Percntg>=70.00)
            BEGIN
            
                SET @max_irow=NULL
                SELECT @max_irow=MAX(irow) FROM #tmp_Cluster

                TRUNCATE TABLE #tmp_Cluster

                INSERT INTO #tmp_Cluster(irow,Product,Ids,Sales,Cluster,Percntg)
                SELECT  irow,product,ids,sales,@cluster,sales/SUM(sales) OVER(PARTITION BY ISNULL(Cluster,1))*100.00
                FROM #Customers
                WHERE Cluster=0 AND irow<=@max_irow+1

            END
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #tmp_Cluster WHERE Percntg>=70.00)
            BEGIN
        
                UPDATE A SET A.Cluster= @cluster
                FROM #Customers A
                INNER JOIN #tmp_Cluster B
                ON A.Product=B.Product
                AND A.Ids=B.Ids
                AND A.irow=B.irow
            END

                SELECT @Id=MAX(Irow) FROM #Customers WHERE Cluster<>0
                SELECT @cluster=MAX(Cluster)+1 FROM #Customers WHERE Cluster<>0

            BREAK;

        END     
 
        TRUNCATE TABLE #tmp_Cluster
    
    END

    SELECT Product,Ids,Sales,Cluster FROM #Customers
```